# Stripping irrelevant parts of a web page

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

Is there a API or systematic way of stripping irrelevant parts of a web page while scraping it via Python? For instance, take this very page -- the only important part is the question and the answers, not the side bar column, header, etc. One can guess things like that, but is there any smart way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the approach from the [Readability](https://www.readability.com/) bookmarklet, with at least two Python implementations available:

- [decruft](http://www.minvolai.com/blog/decruft-arc90s-readability-in-python/)
- [python-readability](https://github.com/gfxmonk/python-readability)

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.  In specific cases, if you know something about the structure of the site you are scraping, you can use a tool like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: There are some heuristic approaches to identifying important parts of a document.  Some of them use NLP, some use size of rendered element, and I'm sure there are hybrids of the two approaches and other flavors entirely.  I don't know the names of any such algorithms off the top of my head, but they do exist.

Either way, +1 for Beautiful Soup.  Definitely the way to go for starters.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to compare the structure of multiple webpages that share the same template. In this case you would compare multiple SO questions. Then you can determine which content is static (useless) or dynamic (useful).

This field is known as *wrapper induction*. Unfortunately it is harder than it sounds!

Answer (score 0):

This git hub project solves your problem, but it's in Java. May be worth a look: [goose](https://github.com/jiminoc/goose)